# Excel macro in Personal workbook not visible in code generated Excel application and workbook

Tags: c#, office-interop, visual-studio-addins, excel-addins

I made a small macro and saved it in my Personal macro workbook. Tested it with new Excel workbooks and it works (I am able to see it in different workbooks). 
However, when i programmatically generate new excel workbook, I don't see the macro. Is there anyway to fix this and have the macro visible in that workbook too?

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application exc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
exc.Visible = true;
exc.Workbooks.Add();
ExcelWorksheet = exc.ActiveSheet;
```

this is the code I use to generate excel workbook.

Comment: in what context are you running this code? is it run under your credentials?

Answer (score 0):

```
       var excelApp1 = new Excel.Application();
        // Make the object visible.
        excelApp1.Visible = true;

        // Create a new, empty workbook and add it to the collection returned 
        // by property Workbooks. The new workbook becomes the active workbook.
        // Add has an optional parameter for specifying a praticular template. 
        // Because no argument is sent in this example, Add creates a new workbook. 
        excelApp1.Workbooks.Add();

        // This example uses a single workSheet. 
        Excel._Worksheet workSheet1 = excelApp1.ActiveSheet;
```